# MergExt - pQuality in mergAV

Tags: video-capture, livecode

> pQuality – (optional with “medium” default) the quality of the video
>   - high
>   - medium
>   - low
>   - 640×480
>   - 1280×720
>   - 960×540

Do you if there a way to know what video capture quality the current device supports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about mergAVPick... you can set the quality in mergAVCamSet too but it looks like your quoting mergAVPick docs.

I'll amend the docs to clearly state this but there are some quality values that were introduced in different SDKs:

- high 3.1+
- 640x480 4.0+
- medium 3.1+
- low 3.1+
- 1280x720 5.0+
- 960x540 5.0+

So you could check the systemVersion if you want to use anything other than mow,medium,high